# scikit-learn: High / low value for C in SVM

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I'm playing with scikit-learn. Looking into the [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#parameters-of-the-rbf-kernel) and [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) they say:

> A low `C` makes the decision surface smooth, while a high `C` aims at classifying all training examples correctly.

The default value is 1.0, which is used by most of the examples. [I also found the value C=100](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#machine-learning-the-problem-setting).

What is meant by "low" and high for `C`?

Answer (score 2):

The loss function in SVM consists of both Classification error and Margin error.

Now `C` is constant that attaches itself to the classification error as given below:

```
SVM_Error = C*Classfication Error + Margin Error
```

So, the high value of `C` means that classification error will be more than the marginal error and therefore model will focus on classifying all the data points accurately. Conversely, if the low value of `C` means that marginal error will be more than the classification error and therefore model will focus creating the larger margin for the hyperplane